# How to create a subclass of thread Class properly in C++(subclass of std::thread)

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I am trying to create a class `Parallel` which is a subclass of `std::thread`,therefore my class is defined in `Parallel.h`,but the main method defined in separate file `main.cpp` in same project(in visual studio).When I create an instance of `Parallel` and execute `join()` function in `main()` method as below code segment:
I am new to C++, here is the "Parallel.h"-

```
#include<thread>
using namespace std;
namespace Para{
class Parallel:thread
{
public:

    static void run(){

    }
    Parallel(void)
    {
    }

    virtual ~Parallel(void)
    {
    }

    inline static void start(Parallel* p){
                // (*p).join();
    }

    virtual void Parallel::start(thread& t){

    }
    static void parallelize(Parallel& p1,Parallel& p2){

    }
    inline virtual Parallel* operator=(thread* t){
        return  static_cast<Parallel*>(t);
    }
}
```

//in main.cpp

```
void main(){

    Parallel p;
    p.join();
    thread t(print);
     t.join();
     system("Pause");

}
```

Problem is how to define a proper subclass of a thread class having a overloaded constructor taking function name as a parameter,also 
when defined `p.join()` compiler given following errors in VS2012:

> Error  2   error C2247: 'std::thread::join' not accessible because 'Para::Parallel' uses 'private' to inherit from 'std::thread'   C:\Users\Gamer\Desktop\PROJECQ\VC++@OMAQ\CQ47\CQ47\main.cpp 11
>
> 3  IntelliSense: function "std::thread::join" (declared at line 209 of "H:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\thread") is inaccessible c:\Users\Gamer\Desktop\PROJECQ\VC++@OMAQ\CQ47\CQ47\main.cpp    11

Comment: Inheriting from Standard Library classes is generally a bad idea. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: Can you provide the header as well?

Comment: If you're asking about it you should at least show the `Parallel` class declaration.

Comment: I need to create a subclass of thread class,as in java we can create our own thread class but it's heavily depends upon JVM,but here I want to create a class with my own functions also every instance of this class should be a thread that's why,

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga In Java you *need* to create a Thread subclass because of how the Thread class is designed. In C++ you do not need to do so, *and it is the wrong way to do it*. In C++, the correct way to create a thread is not to subclass `std::thread`, but simply to pass a function or function object of your choosing to `std::thread`'s constructor.

Comment: @ jalf I know that,but my objective was to defined a class with set of functionality and each instance of it perform as a thread(concurrent action) so I think std::thread providing some basic functionality,Sorry If I misunderstood,Need your kind help.

Comment: Why don't you use _composition_ instead of _inheritance_, i.e. using `std::thread` as a member variable of your class?

Comment: I done that but here I want to create my own class that can replace the using of std::thread class with extended functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error about "uses 'private' to inherit" when you try to call 'p.join()' is because you have written:

```
    class Parallel:thread
```

When you should have written:

```
    class Parallel : public thread
```

The default is private inheritance, which means all methods of the base class become private on the inheriting class. You have to specify that the inheritance should be public if you want them to be accessible.

Comment: thank you.But previously everyone mentioned that constructing a subclass of std::thread class isn't a wise idea.I want exact reason or definition for the cause,could you help me on that?

Answer (score 1):

In Java functions are not first class citizens, so everything related to functions is achieved via classes and inheritance, like in the implementation of the Observer pattern of Swing: You create a class which implements the interface of the handler of the event (You have to implement an entire class only to provide a function).

The same occurs with threads: Because you cannot pass a function to the thread (Because Java doesn't have the concept of "function"), you have to derive from the thread class implementing your own function to execute, or pass a class that implement the `Runnable` interface which provides the function to be executed (Exactly as in the `Observer` case).

In C++ functions are first class citizens (In the form of function pointers, lambdas, functors, etc), so the mechanism here is to pass the function to be executed to the thread.

If what you have is a OO dessign, consider to fit the thread through composition (Store the thread of execution as a member of the class) instead of inheriting from it.

#### Note: Java 8

Only as a sidenote, Java 8 implements lambdas, and provides **function references (Hooray!) through them**. But it implements lambdas using interfaces because it appers that in Java functions never will be first class citizens.  The problem with interfaces is it breaks completely the generallity of lambdas: A lambda can be used in any context which matches its signature. Thats not true with Java lambdas: You have to implement the same interface.

Comment: That's not entirely true. In Java you can pass a `Runnable` to the constructor of the `Thread` object, and I would say that's the recommended way to create threads in Java.

Comment: @nosid `Runnable` is exactly the same case as `Observer`: You have to implement an entire class only to provide a function, because Java doesn't have functions as entities.

Comment: @Manu343726 I am asking,Is there any possibility create a subclass of std::thread ?

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga no, because standard classes are like monsters, its very difficult to fullfill all of its requeriments when you inherit from them. Consider to use composition, as nosid suggested.

Comment: @Manu343726 java 8 we will have lambda function integration,I am using netbeans 7.4 beta with JDK 8 (https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga have you readed my note? I have showed the problems with Java lambdas on it.

Comment: @Manu343726 Got it,you are correct.But regarding my question do you have any solution about construct a subclass(child) of std::thread in C++ ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38687/discussion-between-buddhika-chaturanga-and-manu343726)

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga YES: **Simply don't do it. Java and C++ are very different languages. Each of them have different ways to do the same thing.**

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga no, no chat. We have explained you why you shouldn't try to inherit from `std::thread`, and you are asking again again about that, regardless of our answers.

Comment: @Manu343726 thank you for your advice bro.I will use std::thread onwards.

Comment: @Manu343726 your answer helped me .. thank you.Java 7/8 & C++11 threading so difference.